# I want a sql query for a specific requirement

Tags: sql

There a table in which some name created and data and time saved in a column, but the thing is that if I do something with name(not changin name just update other related field) it will update in table as a new row with update time(time saved in a same column where created date saved,but the previous data of that same name didn't deleted).

Now I want a query of all the name which has been Created(only creation data needed not updated) after the a speficic date. if the name didn't created after that date then no need that data

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: Like `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE yourdatefield > 'somedate';`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need below -

```
SELECT name, MIN(CREATE_DATE)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE CREATE_DATE >= &INPUT_DATE
GROUP BY name
```

This will fetch you the record with the minimum input date which would always be the created date. If a records is never updated, It will fetch that record.

Let me know, if you require something else.